# Scroll down section of webpage with selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scroll down a specific div in a webpage (ticker box in facebook) using selenium (with python).

I can find the element, but when i try to scroll it down using:

```
header = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tickerActivityStories")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', header)
```

Nothing happens.

I've found a lot of answers, but mostly are for selenium in java, so i would like to know if it's possible to do it from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found a lot of answers, but mostly are for selenium in java

There is no difference, selenium has the same api in java and python, you just need to find the same function in python selenium.

First of all check if your JS works in the browser(if not, try scroll parent element).

Also you can try :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
header.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: Will try both of them tomorrow and post back what happened! Thanks!

Comment: Tested and working, that was the problem, i was in a non-scrollable division, thanks a lot bro!